# How to use var in Java

Tags: java

I am stuck on how to use var. Is there any difference between this two?

```
var input = (String) result.get("some field from DB");
String input = (String) result.get("some field from DB");
```

Comment: The second line 3 chars shorter. No other differences.

Answer (score 0):

In java 10 and above when you use `var` you are allowing the compiler to attempt to decide what the variables type should be. In your example your casting a String so it will give that variable type String.

In your second example you are specifically telling the compiler that your variable is of type String.

The second is safer if you know what your variable type will be as it leaves no confusion down to the compile.

Comment: But it is the same? Except only shorter

Comment: At compile time they would be the same yes.